# What is this type of UI component called and how it is built?

Tags: user-interface, widget, controls

This is probably a very simple question, but I need to know what this type of form is called. I need to figure out how to build it for an application I am working on an can't find any info anywhere. I drew up a quick image in Photoshop to illustrate what it looks like.

[image: Image I made to describe what I am looking for]

Comment: Build it with a couple of listboxes and some buttons. I don't know what it's called, although I've implemented it a few times!

Comment: A pick list with sort?

Comment: I've heard a few times of it being called a "left-right selector/chooser" or "list builder", but probably "pick list/list picker" as suggested by Valamas is the best...

Comment: I don't think there's an actual name for that. Do you have any problems when trying to implement it?

Comment: I have never built one... that is my issue. I am looking for some good references. Basically I have a database with a few names, and the order in the DB is the order they appear in the software, I was hoping to re-sort them to be more appealing.

Comment: I googled 'select list from left to right' there were a few relevant hits.

Comment: apparently Windows calls it a List Builder "Allow users to create a list of choices by adding one item at a time, and optionally setting the list order"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good reference in C# for a basic PickList implemetation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12776/Basic-C-PickList

[image: Snip]

Comment: Between this answer and Quetzalcoatl I should be able to get this silly thing working. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The bulk of it looks like a PickList.  [Here's one](https://click.apache.org/docs/extras-api/org/apache/click/extras/control/PickList.html) implementation.

As Valamas mentioned, it also seems to have the extra feature of some sorting functionality, but this is not standard.

Answer (score 5):

1) Prepare two "lists" (components, controls, widgets, ..) in the UI framework of your choice. Add two buttons and add two click handlers for add/remove and also some for the ok/cancel. And two buttons&handlers for up/down.

2) At startup, fill the left widget with all known items.

3) In the clickhandler for "add" button, check what is "selected/highlighted" on the left list widget, remove it from that list and add it to the right list.

4) In the clickhandler for "remove" button, check what is "selected/highlighted" on the right list widget, remove it from that list and add it to the left list.

5) in the handler for up (or down) again check what is selected/highlighted on the right list. check not only what, but also at what index. Add one to that (or subtract) and then move the item to the new position. The 'move' operation will depend heavily on what widget you are using. It will either provide you with easy 'move item' method, or not - in which case you'd first remove the item and then reinsert the item at new position.

6) in the clickhandler for "OK", read all items from the right list and return them as the final selection.

and, well, that'd be all.

Comment: this was helpful in getting the planning done, thank you sir !!